# Issue with Open in Chrome links on iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I tried to follow a comment link from the Inbox into the question on the iOS app. A message popped up saying **Page Not Found** but that the link could be opened in Chrome; presumably the OP deleted it. However the link it tried to open when clicked was `https://posts/comments/69702622`...

Similar behaviour occurs when I try to click through a link to a deleted post from another post or comment; e.g. following the link in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239455/why-are-python-generator-frames-gi-frame-f-back-attribute-always-none#comment69678719_41239455) then clicking Open in Chrome takes me to `https://q/41223344`.

This only happens with Chrome, switching my preferred browser to Safari works just fine.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: @Cai yes, I clicked a reply in the inbox within the app. I can recreate with any of the comments from http://stackoverflow.com/q/41250491/3001761. Inbox -> comment on deleted question -> page not found -> broken link in Chrome.

Comment: @Cai that was the original, but I just recreated with a link to a deleted question from a comment. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Very strange, seems the issue is only with Chrome. You get the correct link if you set your preferred browser to and open with Safari.

Comment: Looks like it's any link to a deleted Q too, nothing specific to comments (type the URL of a deleted Q in search to test)

Comment: @Cai so it does! Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3, shipping in January.

When opening the deleted question in the browser, the link is passed as "/q/41223344" relative to "https://stackoverflow.com".  To open the link in Chrome, I convert the NSURL to NSURLComponents, update the scheme to point to the Chrome app get the resulting URL.  Unfortunately, I was telling it do discard the base URL so the resulting URL was "googlechromes://q/41223344".

Just had to change a `NO` to a `YES`.

Comment: *"No. No, the other no!"* Sounds good, will accept when it ships.

Comment: Or, to put it another simpler way, you didn't test it before shipping it.