# Open in Safari opens the duplicate on closed questions

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, ios-app, redirection

In the iOS app, if you click the "Safari" button on a question closed as a duplicate, it opens *the duplicate* in the browser.

Bizarrely this doesn't happen if I choose Chrome as my preferred browser (so I have to choose between this and [Issue with Open in Chrome links on iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288476/248731) until the next version arrives!)

I suppose this may be a feature, not a bug, but given that you can't vote to delete from the app it's useful to open closed questions in a browser to do that. If I wanted to open the duplicate in a browser that's only one extra click anyway.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't see anything newer in the App Store, do you have a beta?

Comment: You're most likely logged in automatically in Chrome, while not logged in with Safari. Visitors who are not logged in users are automatically redirected when there are no answers, that is by design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably not logged in on that specific site (in mobile Safari). Anonymous users are automatically [redirected away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232392/295232) from questions closed as duplicates.