# Notification link broken

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, ios-app

I just got a notification via the app for a new [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/70572947) (on Stack Overflow) that was added to a question that was put on hold and subsequently deleted by the OP.

When I clicked the notification, the app opened with an appified 404:

> Page Not Found
>   We couldn't find the page you requested
>
> Open in Chrome

If you don't want to open deleted questions in the app (which I can do in browser), then show something better than [a 404 message](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247149/let-me-do-something-with-a-comment-link-to-a-deleted-question), such as

> Sorry, that post has been deleted, and this app doesn't support viewing deleted posts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Open in Chrome links on iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288476/issue-with-open-in-chrome-links-on-ios-app)

Comment: @alex problem 2 is a dupe. Still leaves problem 1 though.